# trigger compiled successfully but doesnt update

Tags: oracle

I am tring to write a trigger to track a table.

I have a table 1 and table 2 . When I Insert data into the table 1 , the trigger succefuly insert the same data into table 2 , how ever when I update the table1 the table2 still have the same same data 
the tabels DDL:

> tab1
>   id number (6); 
>   info varhcar2(20);

tab2

> id number (6);
>   info varchar2(20);
>   id_new number (6);
>   info_new varchar2(20);

the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tab2_logs
after INSERT or update or delete
   ON tab1
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN


IF INSERTING THEN
insert into tab2_logs (
id, info)
values (:new.id ,:new.info);

else if updating then
update tab2_logs set 
id = :old.id,
info = :old.info,
id_new = :new.id,
info_new = :new.id
 where id = :new.id;

end if;
end if;
END;
```

I did commit in my query and the trigger compiled succedfuly

Comment: Shouldn't your where clause check for the `:old.id` as the `:new.id` is not known there yet?

Comment: you mean to put it as ' where id = :old.id ' ? it didnt work as well

Comment: And I think you ment to use `ELSIF`

Comment: I correct the elsif , still not updating

Comment: TBH your whole logic has a flaw as you can update your logtable only once, then it's not working, because you are compaing to a new id that is no longer existent in the logtable

Comment: @Armunin I put the old it , still not updating , how should i solve it then?

Comment: See my suggested answer. It's working for me this way. Not sure if it is what you were looking for

Comment: ok the problem is with the condition when i remove the where condition the field was updatet . I did added :old.id . it didnt work, it seems the values for the new or cold seems empty maybye i should write an insert it at first to hold the id. in such way it will work , I guess.

Comment: As I said above, it will only work once, because of the whole logic behind your logging. Did you test it with my trigger and the change to tab2_logs that I suggested?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42115/discussion-between-armunin-and-moudiz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:
Change tab2_logs to the columns:

```
id, info, id_old, info_old
```

And then use the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tab2_logs AFTER
    INSERT OR
    UPDATE OR
    DELETE
        ON tab1 FOR EACH ROW DECLARE BEGIN IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT
    INTO
        tab2_logs
        (
            id,
            info
        )
        VALUES
        (
            :new.id ,
            :new.info
        );
elsif updating THEN
    UPDATE
        tab2_logs
    SET
        id       = :new.id,
        info     = :new.info,
        id_old   = :old.id,
        info_old = :old.info
    WHERE
        id = :old.id;
END IF;
END;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52b54/3)**

Comment: it didnt work, I remove the condition, its a test table. if the problem with the condition then it should update

Comment: Which condition did you remove? It is working that way for me, if your trigger and/or table is different, then maybe post the whole information in your question so I can adjust my answer.

Comment: You fire the trigger on DELETE but inside the trigger you don't do any action, i.e. `IF DELETING THEN` is missing. Did you provide the full trigger code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

add dbms_output.put_line() for finding execution path

-- old answer -- have no sense according last comment
look like your update do not found record int tab2_log maybe you need change

```
where id = :new.id;
```

to

```
where id = :old.id;
```

also for logging purposes better way (on my mind)

```
create or replace trigger tab2_logs
    after insert or update or delete on tab1
    for each row
begin
    if INSERTING or updating then
        -- also need add information about time and user who change row
        insert into tab2_logs (id, info) values (:new.id, :new.info);
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: actually in my real code its :old.id not :new.id and in my real code I did add that to add more information SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL') into V_USERNAME  FROM dual;

Comment: add dbms_output.put_line for finding execution way in trigger

Comment: i should add the triger inside put line ? like this  dbms_output.put_line(trigername) ?

Comment: I'm use something like this dbms_output.put_line('point 1'); dbms_output.put_line('point 2'); to check the execution way. after update just look at dbms_output and you should understand executeion way

Comment: so what problem add dbms_output and run update after that? maybe I do not understand your problem?